# Logs in release mode react-native?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, android-studio

I have a React-Native app, and I want to know is there a way to see `logs` output after generated a **release** ask?

I can do it in debug mode as usual but I have some things that should be tested after release, so I want to ensure everything works well and sees my `console.log()` output.

I specifically want it in **Android** right now.

Comment: Uh old days:D i used Sentry it's Awesome